# Deploy asp.net core app on Linux - redirect url problem

Tags: linux, docker, web, asp.net-core, deployment

I'm now during deploy asp .net core mvc app on Linux and one thing is very confused for me.

So on main page `Home/Index` I have buttons to adding products to cart and I do that by `data-url` with `@Url.Action` where I declare controller, action and some args.

On Windows both on local environment and remote server everything work ok, so in the `Request Url` I can see in my case:

```
http://domain/Cart/AddToCart?some_args
```

`Request Method` is GET and `Status Code` is 302 Found and in `Response Header` I get `Location` to next action to do.

But on Linux instead correct `Request Url` I get everytime:

```
http://domain/Home/Index
```

.. and no action is done.

I tried by nginx and now I'm trying on Docker platform, but effect is the same - redirect url not working..

**Edit:**

Added my `data-url` code:

```
data-url="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {arg1 = value1, arg2 = value2, arg3 = value3} )"
```

and *AddToCart* action:

```
public RedirectToActionResult AddToCart(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
    var product = get product from repo

    if (product != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ActionAsync");
}
```

Comment: Share us your view code with `data-url` and your controller action code.

Comment: Shared.. but I think code is ok, as I explained, on Windows system its working, problem exists only on Linux so probably its some server configuration problem.